# How to enable cross origin on wildfly?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cross-domain, wildfly

I deployed my spring boot app by using wild fly.
But when I inspect my application there it is given that

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

I just want to allow my domain for example like:-

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '192.10.0.1:9991'
```

How do I achieve it or implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure this while providing a bean of type `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins("192.10.0.1:9991")
            .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "DELETE");

        // Add more mappings...
    }
}
```

The [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors) provides more detailed information about how to configure CORS.

Comment: Ok let me implement it